# A RenderFlex overflowed by 8.1 pixels on the bottom using ListView

Tags: flutter

I have a screen which contains an input field and below a list with text messages. I want the list to be scrollable, but the input field should stay to the top all the time. When doing it like below I got the message `A RenderFlex overflowed by 8.1 pixels on the bottom.` which means my Column grows too much. Instead I want the list to become scrollable.

```
Material(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 5),
                  child: TextFormField(...),
                ),
                ListView.builder(
                        controller: scrollController ,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: comments.length,
                        itemBuilder: buildTile)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Wrap parent Container in SingleChildScrollView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap your `ListView` inside an `Expanded` widget.

```
Material(
  child: Container(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 5),
          child: TextFormField(...),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            controller: scrollController ,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: comments.length,
            itemBuilder: buildTile,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Reason for the error:**
`Column` expands to the maximum size in `main` axis direction (vertical axis), and so does the `ListView`.

**Solution One**

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: ListView(...),
    )
  ],
)
```

**Solution Two**

add `SingleChildScrollView` as parent of `Column` widget

and add the following properties for listView

```
  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
```